# rearrange string with mixed languages (LTR + RTL)?

Tags: c#, .net, string, right-to-left

I have a text with mixed languages, (one  LTR and the other RTL).when sending the string on SMTP the string gets mixed up  .Is there any way to recognize the string ?

Answer (score 2):

RTL only affects the *display* of text, not the transmission.  Not sure what "mixed up" might mean but I'd recommend you take a good look at the MailMessage.BodyEncoding property.  The default is ASCII, not suitable for sending the kind of characters used in a RTL language.  If that doesn't help then consider that the problem might actually be caused by the mail reader you are using.  It might not support RTL or cannot handle a mix.