# How .NET's regex engine treats RTL+LTR mixed strings?

Tags: c#, regex, hebrew, right-to-left

I have a mixed Hebrew/english string to parse.
The string is built like this:

```
[3 hebrew] [2 english 2] [1 hebrew],
```

So, it can be read as: 1 2 3, and it is stored as 3 2 1 (exact byte sequence in file, double-checked in hex editor, and anyway RTL is only the [display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752579/rearrange-string-with-mixed-languages-ltr-rtl/3752910#3752910) attribute). .NET regex parser has [RTL option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx#RightToLeft), which (when given for plain LTR text) starts processing from right side of the string.

I am wondering, when this option should be applied to extract [3 hebrew] and [2 english] parts from the string,or to check if [1 hebrew] matches the end of the string? Are there any hidden specifics or there's nothing to worry about (like when processing any LTR string with special unicode characters)?

---

Also, can anyone recommend me a good RTL+LTR text editor? (afraid that VS Express displays the text wrong sometimes, and if it can even start messing the saved strings - I would like to re-check the files without using hex editors anymore)

Comment: If you stored the string as 1 2 3 you could split the two strings, read them using RTL, then read the third string using the default option.  The only way I know how to enable RTL support is enabled it within Windows.

Comment: The script direction has nothing to do with this though. Regex's RightToLeft is a misnomer based on assumptions about left-to-right scripts, as I explain in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RightToLeft` option refers to the order through the character sequence that the regular expression takes, and should really be called `LastToFirst` since in the case of Hebrew and Arabic it is actually left-to-right, and with mixed RLT and LTR text such as you describe the expression "right to left" is even less appropriate.

This has a minor effect on speed (will only matter if the searched text is massive) and on regular expressions that are done with a `startAt` index (searching those earlier in the string than `startAt` rather than later in the string).

Examples; let's hope the browers don't mess this up too much:

```
string saying = "למכות is in כתר"; //Just because it amuses me that this is a saying whatever way round the browser puts malkuth and kether.
string kether = "כתר";
Console.WriteLine(new Regex(kether, RegexOptions.RightToLeft).IsMatch(saying));//True
Console.WriteLine(new Regex(kether, RegexOptions.None).IsMatch(saying));//True, perhaps minutely faster but so little that noise would hide it.
Console.WriteLine(new Regex(kether, RegexOptions.RightToLeft).IsMatch(saying, 2));//False
Console.WriteLine(new Regex(kether, RegexOptions.None).IsMatch(saying, 2));//True
//And to show that the ordering is codepoint rather than physical display ordering:
Console.WriteLine(new Regex("" + kether[0] + ".*" + kether[2]).IsMatch(saying));//True
Console.WriteLine(new Regex("" + kether[2] + ".*" + kether[0]).IsMatch(saying));//False
```

Comment: `Reverse` is better name.. but wait, for what reason this should be an option and not a function.. oh, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string-in-c-sharp-2-0 - they even have no reverse() in .NET.

Comment: Reversing has its own complications.